# SQLite Delete Cascade not working: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

Tags: java, android, database, android-sqlite

I have two table:

**Child Table**

```
 public static final String SQL_CREATE_TAB_COMMENT = "CREATE TABLE " +TABLE_COMMENT+ "( " + KEY_COMMENT + "  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , " + COLUMN_EMMET + " TEXT NOT NULL , " +COMMENT+  " TEXT , "+IMAGCOM+" TEXT , "+FORMAT+" TEXT NOT NULL , "+DATECMTCREATION+" TEXT , "+TAGSTATUTCMT+" TEXT , "+ COLUMN_COMMENT_KEY_POST +" INT NOT NULL , "+EMETPOST_PHONE+ " TEXT, " +DEST_PHONE+ " TEXT, "  + IDCMTEMET + " TEXT,"+VISITEDCMT+" TEXT, "+TAB_IMAGES + " TEXT, "+IS_DOWNLOADED + " TEXT,"+FILEDOC+" TEXT,  FOREIGN KEY(" + COLUMN_COMMENT_KEY_POST + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_POST_NEW + "(_id)  ON DELETE CASCADE )";
```

**Parent Table**

```
  public static final String SQL_CREATE_TAB_POST_NEW = "CREATE TABLE " +TABLE_POST_NEW+ "( " +KEY_POST+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ," +EMMET+ " TEXT NOT NULL , " +TEXT+  " TEXT NOT NULL , "+ IMAG +" TEXT ,"+TYPE+ " TEXT ," +DEST+ " TEXT ," +IDPOSTEMET+ " TEXT NOT NULL, " +CMT_NON_LU+ " TEXT, " +DATELASTEVENT+" TEXT, " +DATECREATION+ " TEXT, " +TAGSTATUT+ " TEXT,"+COUNTER_DEST+" TEXT,"+VISITED+" TEXT,"+ NAME_GROUP+ " TEXT,"+ IDGROUP + " TEXT, "+TAB_IMAGES + " TEXT, "+IS_DOWNLOADED +" TEXT, "+COLUMN_POST_KEY_CONTACT+ " INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, "+LABEL_IMAGES+" TEXT,"+TAB_FILE+" TEXT)";
```

Now If I am deleting parent row I have this error:

> FOREIGN KEY constraint failed   Error Code : 787 (SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_FOEIGNKEY)
>       Caused By : Abort due to constraint violatio

```
 public PosteManager openForWrite(){

    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    //db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON");
    db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);
    return this;
}

public int deletePoste(int posteId){

    openForWrite();
    int delete = db.delete(DbHelper.TABLE_POST_NEW, DbHelper.KEY_POST + "=" + posteId, null);
    close();

    return delete;

}
```

> KEY_POST = _id; and I test  COLUMN_COMMENT_KEY_POST = _id and COLUMN_COMMENT_KEY_POST = post_id

I have the same error

I test your code and I have this in `Log.d("TABLESQL","The creation SQL for table "` :

```
D/TABLESQL: The creation SQL for table comment_tbl_new is 
    CREATE TABLE comment_tbl_new( _commentid  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , Emetteur TEXT NOT NULL , comment TEXT , imageCom TEXT , format TEXT NOT NULL , Datecmtcreation TEXT , Tagstatutcmt TEXT , post_id INT NOT NULL , emetPost_phone TEXT, Dest_phone TEXT, idcmtemet TEXT,visited TEXT, tab_image TEXT, idownloaded TEXT,filedoc TEXT,  FOREIGN KEY(post_id) REFERENCES post_tbl_new(_id) )
06-14 00:11:06.845 18468-18468/com. D/TABLESQL: The creation SQL for table comment_tbl is 
    CREATE TABLE comment_tbl( _commentid  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , Emetteur TEXT NOT NULL , comment TEXT , imageCom TEXT , format TEXT NOT NULL , Datecmtcreation TEXT , Tagstatutcmt TEXT , _id INT NOT NULL , emetPost_phone TEXT, Dest_phone TEXT, idcmtemet TEXT,visited TEXT, tab_image TEXT, idownloaded TEXT,filedoc TEXT,  FOREIGN KEY(_id) REFERENCES post_tbl_new(_id)  ON DELETE CASCADE )
```

Comment: Uncomment  //db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON");

Comment: I test with db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON");  it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From API 16+, you should enable foreign key constraint like this in `SQLITEOpenHelper` class:

```
@Override
public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db){
    db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);
}
```

As the foreign key constraint is enabled, You can check if another table is not referring child table and it's foreign key is not cascade. Also `") REFERENCES " + TABLE_POST_NEW + "(_id)` have you defined `_id` column in your `TABLE_POST_NEW` ?

Comment: I don't have SQLOpenHelper class on my project

Comment: I have only SQLiteDatabase class

Comment: my mistake its SQLITEOpenHelper

Comment: If FOREIGN KEY SUPPORT were not turned on then there would be no FOREIGN KEY constraint failed error.

Comment: ON DELETE CASCADE enables a sequence that allows the deletions from the parent to propagate (cascade down). Thus delete a parent will deleting the related children.

Comment: @MikeT You are right. I have updated the answer. Sometimes that also creates a problem.

Comment: @Derek, I found SQLITEOpenHelper but File is only readable. So I put  onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) in my DbHelper and I add  super.onConfigure(db);

Comment: Yes I have old table I drop it, and now it works thank you

Comment: I can't I have only 5 reputation I need 15 to vote, sorry.

Comment: Thank you so muuuuch :))